# Trying to replace \r\n\n but not \r\n in a file

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed

This is using  GNU sed version 4.2.1 but I've also tried awk and Perl without any success so far.

I have a file that is produced by a COBOL program (on Linux) and it has what can be considered nonstandard CRLF instead of LF (CRLF of course being Windows line terminators)  but that's what I need to retain - anything CRLF stays.

So `\r\n` sequences stay.

What I need to replace are occasional `\r\n\n` sequences with `\r\n\r\n` without disturbing anything else.

I have to match this file I produce using diff with the original file produced on BSD or SCO or something.

This doesn't work and I expect the first `/n` is getting stripped by `Sed` as the line terminator

```
sed -e 's/\r\n\n/\r\n\r\n/g'  infile  > outfile
```

I tried `hex 0x` and also double escape too

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you just add a CR before any LF that isn't already preceded by one.

```
s/ (?<!\r) (?=\n) /\r/xg
```

In a program that alters the data in a file it would look something like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use open IO => ':raw';

my $data = do {
  local $/;
  <>;
};

$data =~ s/ (?<!\r) (?=\n) /\r/xg;

print $data;
```

and you would run it like

```
perl add_cr.pl myfile > newfile
```

or, if you wanted to modify your file in-place (after testing it) you could use just

```
perl -i add_cr.pl myfile
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Borodin, that perl script works fine   -appreciate it

Comment: I expect that your solution will be slower than `s/\r?\n/\r\n/g`.

Comment: s/\r?\n/\r\n/g doesn't work in GNU 4.2.1 sed - or anything else to do with form feeds, line breaks etc as far as I can see (and in the way I am trying to use it) . I'm using sed -e 's/\r?\n/\r\n/g' file1 > file2 and file2 is no different from file1.  It may work in perl though. Speed is not a consideration.

Comment: @ikegami: Well you could time them before commenting! But since your alternative replaces *every* valid `\r\n` with itself I'm betting on mine.

Comment: @Easycoder `\n` will only work in some seds so that may be why this solution is not working for you. The portable way to get a newline in sed is a backslash followed by a literal newline character.

Comment: Maybe, but yours creates two submatches at nearly every single position.

Answer (score 2):

sed being a line oriented tool, `blah\r\n\n` will be a line `blah\r` followed by an empty line. So, add a `\r` to any empty line:

```
sed 's/^$/\r/' infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe "s/\R/\r\n/g" <input.txt >output.txt
```

Magic here is about `\R` which matches any new-line combination accepted by Perl: `\n`, `\r\n` or `\r` alone. As far as I know, `\R` is Perl-only - not supported by `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: @Easycoder: better way to say thank you here is to simply upvote. And most importantly, you should accept answer that you consider best for you

Answer (score 0):

WIth GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
awk -v RS='\r\n\n' -v ORS='\r\n\r\n' '1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try unix2dos utility:  It handle all unix/dos/ and mixture of unix/dos cases.
Note: dos2unix is also a good utility.

Overwrite:

```
unix2dos your-file
```

Create new file:

```
unix2dos < your-file > your-new-file
```